# Importing Twitter Data (csv) into R

Tags: r, text

I have a file of tweets about a teleco in csv format (2176 records). But when I import that into R, only a portion of it is getting imported.

Will someone please guide me on this. Sample data shown below

```
'@wolvertonmanor Wolverton Folk & Blues Festival is included in Folk Orbit #Festival listings 

#nowplaying talk talk - life's what you make it ??

$750 pulsa gratisan dr vodafone tiap bulan kayanya gabakal cukup kalo dipake nlfn? (w/ @PrasetyaLaras & Wenny) ? 

. im missing u in every where and every step..in my life..

Btuk kah boz,,minum molto pasti dah., RT @aliffiandiwang: Anu batuk"@Ninditaelvira: apaan-_-"@aliffiandiwang: *uhukk *uekk *cuihhhh
```

Comment: that's not a CSV file (well, _technically_ it could be considered a one-column, no-header CSV file but that's just silly).  Just use `readLines()`

Comment: @hrbrmstr I agree with you, it doesn't make sense to have it as a csv. I just got it as a csv file. I tried to copy everything into notepad & save as a text file. Then used readLines() to import it to R (tried on both csv & text file) but still imports only 897 lines . I got the following message     ` _tweets <- readLines("Tweets.txt")_
_Warning message:_
_In readLines("Tweets.txt") : incomplete final line found on 'Tweets.txt'_

Comment: Did you add a newline to the end of the file!